# Google Apps Marketplace - Getting all domain users

Tags: python, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I've created a Google Apps Marketplace app with OAuth2 authentication, and I'm able to use a Service Account to list app installation notifications and to get customer info. However, I couldn't find a way of getting a full list of the users in the domain which my app is installed on.

What I've tried so far is adding the scope for the directory api `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly` and calling the directory api, but this returns an error: `Domain cannot use apis.`

How can I list domain users?

**Update:**

After enabling Admin API in the domain management dashboard, I still get an error: `Not Authorized to access this resource/api`. This error doesn't happen when impersonating as the admin user, but I couldn't find a way of getting the admin's username, so I'm still stuck.

Comment: Can you confirm you've enabled the Admin SDK in the Developer Console?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the admin api in the control panel, see https://support.google.com/a/answer/60757?hl=en

UPDATE :
At install time, setup a Setup Url and catch the admin user there. You can configure this in the appsmarket SDK :
[image]

Comment: thanks for the response. I already did it, but still getting an error. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Tzach did you enable the admin sdk in the api/cloud console  ?

Comment: Yes admin sdk is enabled. And when impersonating as the admin user it works.. but I don't have the admin username.

Comment: @Tzach at install time, the current user is admin. Catch him :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers!  Just curious, how did you "catch" the current admin during the redirect to the setup url?

Comment: the admin will have to authenticate by going through the OAuth2 dance when launching the setup url. after this authorization,you know his email address.